# Fail to restore magento on a new domain

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error, restore, mage

I used Ubuntu Desktop to be my server hosting Magento. I have restored the Magento in following way:

1. Import Magento database to MySQL server
2. Copy and paste all the files to `/var/www/html`

Remarks:

Permission: `755`

Magento Version: `1.9.2`

PHP version: `7.0`

Unfortunately, I have got an error related to the code generated by Magento.

```
Fatal error: 
   Uncaught Error: Call to a member function extend() on boolean in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php:600 
Stack trace:
   #0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(278): Varien_Simplexml_Config->extend(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base)) 
   #1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadBase() 
   #2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initBaseConfig() 
   #3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array) 
   #4 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
   #5 /var/www/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') 
   #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600
```

How can I solve this error in order to restore Magento on a new domain?

I have tried to lower the permission to `644` but it failed. Moreover, I have tested that PHP7.0 can also open the installation page of a new Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have tried to set permissions of folders and files but still it seems to be a problem with folder and file permission.

Please try resetting permission using [magento-cleanup.php](https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php)

file.
Please put this file in document root of your magento and run this file from browser.
Please let me know whether it solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

Try clearing cache, and check file permissions are correctly set,

Directories : 755

Files : 644

If this still doesn't work then may be your files are corrupt.